# Error in accentuation in Rmarkdown with self_contained: FALSE and widgets (dygraphs and others)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, dygraphs

I'm trying to make a html Rmarkdown with a dygraphs and using a source file.
When I use `self_contained: TRUE` I don't have a problem, but when I use `self_contained: FALSE` , the legend accentuation goes wrong.

[image: dygraph with self_contained: FALSE. The correct would be "Orgânico"]

If I use without the source, that's OK, but I need to use sources in my case.

Here I put a reproducible code:

the source (tilemaker.R)

```
ptcolsumm <-  c("Usuários", "Sessões", "Pageview Único", "Pageviews",  "Tempo Médio", "Rejeição", "Taxa de Rejeição", "Taxa de Saída", "não sei", "ACENTUAÇÃO", "Teste")

organic <- data.frame(organic = as.numeric(c(186,640,278,11,267,117,41,17,38)))
organic <- as.ts(organic)

# Facebook impressions by type
teste <- dygraph(organic) %>%
  dySeries("organic", label = "Orgânico") %>%
  dyLegend(width = 400, show = "always") %>%
  dyOptions(fillGraph = TRUE, fillAlpha = 0.2, drawGrid = FALSE, drawPoints = TRUE, pointSize = 2)
```

The Rmd:

````
---
title: "Habits"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: flatly
    highlight: tango
    self_contained: FALSE
---
```{r source}
require(magrittr)
require(dygraphs)
source("tilemaker.R", encoding = "UTF-8")
```
<style> /* CSS style to solve the problem with the sparkline tooltip */
.jqstooltip {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
</style>

## Quarterly Results {.tabset}

### By Region

```{r3}

teste

```

### BLOH BLOH 3
TESTE DE 3 DIVISÕES
````

If I don't use the tabs, it's works too, but I need it too.

Comment: @yihui is trying to help in the Rmarkdown Github: https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/686#issuecomment-217179210

Answer (score 0):

@Yihui solved the problem.
The problem was in the html tools package.

To solve the problem immediately:

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/htmltools@bugfix/utf8-preserved-chunks')`
```

I think they will merge the chunk in the next release of the htmltools package and the problem would be solved for all new instalations.